# module.exports is exporting too fast

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, export

I am using JavaScript to access API. I have a few files and am currently linking variables and data via `module.exports`.

The problem is when I `var variableName = require('./file.js')`, it exports the variable before it's been assigned a value (but it is declared), thus it is undefined. What makes this harder is that I can't just create the variable within the function, because I need it to be global. If I could just declare it within the function, it would have to wait until it is declared to be able to access it, thus it would have an assigned value.

Ways around it... well so far the only two ideas I had were plausable.

first, putting `module.exports.variableName` within the function, but that game me literally no data (just blank when I did `console.log(variableName)`) when attempting to check its value from the other files.

The other idea which has worked was to do the following

```
setTimeout(function(){
   module.exports.variableName = variableName;
}, 3000);
```

In other words I actually made it wait, after the API was called, in the last piece of code at the bottom of the file, 3 seconds until it could export the variable.

This surprisingly worked in my files, but I hoped there was a better alternative... because if the API takes more than that to respond then the variable is undefined, or if internet is slow, etc. And also I wanted it to update after the API was called haha, not after the API is called and then 3 seconds or etc.

Any feedback helps! thanks! I'm new(ish) to JavaScript so if you think your answer is a bit more complex than the average Joe would understand, please explain it a little. (if not I can figure it out).

Thanks again!

Edit:

If it helps I'm running this through my OSX Terminal with `node`

here's some file info:

```
//file.js
var balance;
request.post(options, function(error, response, body) { 
   //API call

   var parsed = JSON.parse(body);
   balance = parsed.currency;
   console.log(balance) //defined
});

console.log(balance); //undefined
module.exports.balance = balance;

//other file
var balance = require('./file.js')
var bal = balance;
console.log(bal); //undefined
```

The thing I notice is that the `console.log` outside of the API function is executed first, then the API within it, so you get an undefined output and defined output (in that order). For the "other file" that requires, it first gives the undefined console.log from the **file.js**, then its own undefined console.log of `{ balance: undefined }`, and then the final console.log from **file.js** of a defined value.

Comment: make sure to change to:require('./file.js'); and not require('file.js'); 
if you are not requiring node_modules module

Comment: yeah haha, I changed that bit, it's really `/Users/user/payload.js`. I'll change it to that up top tho, thanks.

Comment: perhaps you could show how you are exporting in `./file.js` - perhaps (likely) it's an asynchronism problem

Comment: ok, let me try to condense the code, it's pretty ugly and long... gimme a few

Comment: *it's an asynchronism problem* - see, it was

Comment: do you "require" file.js from more than one place?

Comment: I only require ./file.js once in the other file, if you'd like I can send you the code.